# If a line has a length less than a number, append to its previous line

Tags: bash

I have a file that looks like this:

```
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGH
ABC
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGH
ABCD
ABCDEFGH
```

Most of the lines have a fixed length of 8. But there are some lines in between that have a length less than 8. I need a simple line of code that appends each of those short lines to its previous line.

I have tried the following code but it takes lots of memory when working with large files.

```
cat FILENAME | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="\t"}{print length($1), $1}' | tr 
'\n' '\t' | sed 's/8/\n/g' | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="";FS="\t"}{print $2, $4}'
```

The output I expect:

```
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHABC
ABCDEFGH
ABCDEFGHABCD
ABCDEFGH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed <FILENAME 'N;/\n.\{8\}/!s/\n//;P;D'
```

- `N;` - append next line to pattern space
- `/\n.\{8\}/` - does second line contain 8 characters?

  - `!s/\n//;` - no: join the two lines
- `P` - print first line of pattern space
- `D` - delete first line of pattern space, start next cycle

Comment: Thank you for your great answer!

Answer (score 5):

If `perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(\n)(.{1,7})$/\2/mg' filename
```

- `-0777` option tells `perl` to slurp all lines.
- The pattern `(\n)(.{1,7})` matches to a line with length less than 8, assigning `\1` to a newline and `\2` to the string.
- The replacement `\2` does not contain the preceding newline and is appended to the previous line.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! This is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Default print without `\n` and append it to the last line when the current line has length 8.
The first and last line are special.

```
awk 'NR==1 {printf $0;next} 
     length($0)==8 {printf "\n"}
     {printf("%s",$0)}
     END { printf "\n" }' FILENAME
```

When you have GNU sed 4.2 (support `-z` option), you can try
**EDIT (see comments):** the inferiour

```
sed -rz 's/\n(.{0,7})\n/\1\n/g' FILENAME
```

Comment: `sed -rz 's/\n(.{0,7}\n)/\1/g' FILENAME` - but won't that try to read entire file into memory?

Comment: @jhnc I think you are right about the memory. Another problem with `sed` solutoin is when you have 2 short lines without a long line between them (the `\n` at the beginning of the line has already been used for the match of the previous line). I don't what OP wants in this situation, with `awk` it is easier to adopt new requirements. 
So go for `awk` and only use my `sed` for small experiments.

Comment: I think your sed script only has a memory problem because of -z (assuming file contains no nulls) which will negate the "stream" part of sed's name. Normal sed programs (cf. my answer) should only read a few lines (+ buffer overhead) at a time.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I only tried the awk one and it works. Also a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you like old traditional tools, you can use [`ed`, the standard text editor](https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html):

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^.\{,7\}$/-,.j' wq | ed -s filename
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! But it didn’t work on my files somehow.